как сделать так, чтобы код работал
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int n;
    cout << "n="; cin >> n;
    int *z = new int[n];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        z[i] = rand() % 15;
        cout << z[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    int size = sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]);

    auto new_end = std::remove_if(z[0], z[n], [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
    size = new_end - z[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << z[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0; //при выполнении этого кода трижды возникает следующая ошибка: нельзя разыменовывать операнд типа "_Fwdlt". Как исправить эту ошибку?
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

sizeof(z) - не догадываетесь, какой он будет? Вы не указали, в какой строке ошибки, но нетрудно увидеть, что вы передаёте remove_if не то, что он хочет - а хочет он итераторы

А я побрюзжу. Что значит "чтоб код работал"? Выбросить все, оставить int main(){} - и код будет работать, только вряд ли это доставит вам радость... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask !!! И еще - в дополнение к MBo — size = new_end - z[0]; тоже какое-то издевательство...
